# jQuery Tooltip - How To Declare 2 Options

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, tooltip

I have been using tooltips on my site:

```
<a title="Help: jQuery UI's theme builder application">Help</a>
```

Within i .JS, i want to use the position and show options:

```
    $( document ).tooltip({     
    show: {
        effect: "slideDown",
        delay: 150,
        track: true
    }       
 });

$( document ).tooltip({
    position: {
        my: "center bottom-20",
        at: "center top",
        using: function( position, feedback ) {
            $( this ).css( position );
            $( "<div>" )
            .addClass( "arrow" )
            .addClass( feedback.vertical )
            .addClass( feedback.horizontal )
            .appendTo( this );
        }
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.ui-tooltip, .arrow:after {
  background: #9FDAEE; 
  border: 1px solid #2BB0D7;
}
.ui-tooltip {
 margin-left: -999em;
 position: absolute;
 border-radius: 5px 5px; -moz-border-radius: 5px; -webkit-border-radius: 5px; 
 box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1); -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
 font-family: Calibri, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
 position: absolute; left: 1em; top: 2em; z-index: 99;
 margin-left: 0; width: 250px;
 font-family: Candara, Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif; font-size: 1.2em; font-weight: bold;
 display: block; padding: 0.2em 0 0.6em 0;
}
.arrow {
 width: 70px;
 height: 16px;
 overflow: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -35px;
 bottom: -16px;
}
.arrow.top {
 top: -16px;
 bottom: auto;
}
.arrow.left {
 left: 20%;
}
.arrow:after {
 content: "";
 position: absolute;
 left: 20px;
 top: -20px;
 width: 25px;
 height: 25px;
 box-shadow: 6px 5px 9px -9px black;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
 tranform: rotate(45deg);
}
.arrow.top:after {
  bottom: -20px;
  top: auto;
}
```

How can i use these together?

Also, i am currently using the **slideDown** feature, is there a '**slideRight**' version?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

// **try like this hope fully it will work**

```
$( document ).tooltip({     
    show: {
        effect: "slideDown",
        delay: 150,
        track: true
    },

    position: {
        my: "center bottom-20",
        at: "center top",
        using: function( position, feedback ) {
            $( this ).css( position );
            $( "<div>" )
            .addClass( "arrow" )
            .addClass( feedback.vertical )
            .addClass( feedback.horizontal )
            .appendTo( this );
        }
    }       
 });
```

Comment: Thanks, seems to work. Any ideas on slideRight? Currently my arrow is at the bottom, would be nice to get it on the left so the toolTip slides to the right.

Comment: You need to use transition function with margin, not sure but kind of similar function. there is no slideRight.